# Will a crontab job wake OS X up from sleep?

Tags: cron

Since OS X has its own task scheduler, launchd, it appears that crontab is a relic.

Hence I'm wondering: Will a cron job (crontab) wake OS X up from sleep?

In case it matters, I'm on Yosemite 10.10.5.

Why I'm not switching to launchd? Laziness:

```
> man launchctl | wc
     463    2975   27730
> man crontab | wc
      72     433    3577
```

The man page is a lot larger, and crontab does everything I need.

Comment: Answer here from [Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/14836/crontab-to-wake-osx-from-sleep).

Comment: I would delve into the Terminal command `pmset` and find out how to schedule startup/wake from sleep. A little testing should show you, as an example, if waking the Mac from sleep at 2:55AM with `pmset`, a `cron` job set for 3:00AM will run as expected.

Comment: Have you tried it? You can answer your own question, let us know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cron` doesn't execute while the computer is asleep. So `cron` can't wake your system.

See: https://superuser.com/a/14846/246895